# HTML & PHPMySQL , Insert many datas into Table from textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Hi I'm trying to insert datas from one textbox (Text Area) but datas should be terminated by lines `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'`

My HTML is

```
    <form method="get" id="testformid" action="upload-datas.php">
    <input type="submit" />
</form> 
<textarea form ="testformid" name="taname" id="taid" cols="35" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

Now if I write in this textare datas like

```
1
22
333
```

How can I make my **upload-datas.php** to terminate datas which it gets from the form on top? 
P.s this is something like CVS file but I like to make it inserting data from textarea!

Comment: All `<input...>` tags must be INSIDE the `<form>...</form>` tags or they are ignored

Comment: how you can see there's no '<input>' outside the '<form>...</form>'

Comment: And of course `<textarea>` counts as an input field

Comment: @RiggsFolly Okay now how should php be to get datas from the form then inserting them terminated by "\n"?

Comment: I'm actually having troubles understanding your question. Can you give me an example of what you want to get when you submit the form?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas My PHP Insert the datas into the Table, but it doesn't terminate it! Datas in not splitted so I want to explode the data automatically from PHP and inserting into table as a row. For every new line, in the table it should be a new row, of course in the same column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple changes that should suffice:

- As RiggsFolly mentioned, the *textarea* should be moved into the form
- I would make the form submit method *POST* instead of *GET*. That way the data won't be appended to the URL (i.e. in the query string).

  `<form method="post" id="testformid">`
- Delimit the new line character (i.e. `\n`) using double quotes:
    e.g. `$lines = explode("\n",$_POST['taname']);`
- Use mysqli functions (e.g. [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/mysqli_connect),  [mysqli_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [mysqli_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [mysqli_execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)) or [PDO functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to insert the data into the database

#### Edit:

The call to [mysqli_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) must be called with all parameters at once, instead of once per parameter. In order to do this with a varying number of parameters, we must use a technique like the one described in [this article](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli).

```
    <?php
    $lines = array();
    $output = '';
    if(array_key_exists('taname',$_POST) && $_POST['taname']) {
        $lines = explode("\n",$_POST['taname']);

        //define $host, $username, $pw, $databaseName before this
        //$host = 'localhost';...etc...
        $connection = mysqli_connect($host,$username, $pw, $databaseName);
        if ($connection) {
            $paramHolders = array_map(function() { return '?';},$lines);

            //update tablename, column name accordingly 
            $insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES ('.implode('), (',$paramHolders).')';
            $statement = mysqli_prepare($connection,$insertQuery);
            //this will be used as the first param to mysql_stmt_bind_param
            // e.g. 'ssss' - one 's' for each line
            $types = str_repeat('s',count($lines));
            $params = array($statement,&$types);
            //add each line by-reference to the list of parameters
            foreach($lines as $index=>$line) {
                $output .= '<div>inserted line: '.$line.'</div>';
                $params[] = &$lines[$index];
            }
            //call mysql_bind_param() with the varying number of arguments
            call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param',$params);
            $statement->execute();
        }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form method="post" id="testformid">
                <textarea name="taname" id="taid" cols="35" wrap="soft"></textarea>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
            <? echo $output; ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Now how to make it to insert the datas into MySQL Database
localhost , root , password, database_name

Comment: it gives to me : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in

Comment: Sorry I mixed up [procedural style](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1849) with [object-oriented style](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1848) - I updated the sample code

Comment: Now when I type more than 1 line at textarea box it gives : mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in ...

Comment: see my updated answer - it allows varying parameters with the call to mysqli_bind_param()